# git local concurrent access

Tags: git, concurrency

I'm writing a piece of code that wrap access to a git repository (it performs write/add/commits and finally pushes)

This application does concurrent access to the git repository (it's a web app, several processes are running in parallel).

I wonder if I should add some kind of locking (ie. mutex) on git operations or if several processes doing git add/commit in parallel is a safe operation

Comment: How did you implement the wrapper? Do you use the official (cli) client?

Comment: I'm also interested in an answer to this question. In particular, git fetch and FETCH_HEAD don't *seem* friendly to concurrent use.

Comment: @Marcus Do you confirm that `git fecth` is still not friendly to concurrent use as of 2019?

Comment: @ManuelVACELET What have you learned regarding concurrency of git commands on the same repo after all these years? What is applicable as of 2019?

Answer (score 7):

If you are wrapping the official git-client (what you -- regarding your comment -- do), you can rely on it and don't need to implement it yourself (once more). It already takes care, that the writing actions appears atomic.